# Do -inf values affect processing time?

Tags: matlab

I am working with a very large matrix (6000x6000x100), and it contains many -inf values. Should I convert these to 0 or NaN to try and speed up processing? I've looked around and can't find literature on this topic, I apologize if it's a stupid question.

Comment: Seems like a quick test with and without the change would answer your question, right?  Have you tried it either way?

Comment: What version of MATLAB do you have?  And how many `-inf` values is "many"?

Comment: 2018b, and on the order of tens of thousands. Running tests as per your suggestion now

Comment: I doubt things will be slower because of the -inf, and I doubly doubt that NaN would make it any faster. Besides, changing -inf to 0 or NaN would change the meaning of your computations and their result. But that all depends on what computations you are talking about.

Comment: @user45919: 10^4 compared with 3.6*10^9 doesn't sound significant.

Comment: That was my concern.I'm looking for different ways to optimize my script, I have a loop that's taking hours.

Comment: Don't guess at where your performance issues are use [profiling](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your computation and number of `-inf` values. If the computation works on finite values, you can change `-inf` to `0` for using from `sparse` to get performance in that computation. Also, have more efficient using from memory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Matlab is implemented, but for answer that question, you must think on a lower-level code, as Matlab's - C generated code or assembly code.

It's the same on a low level language to initialize a bunch of 0's, or a bunch or -X's value?

I don't really know, buy i think that a compiler it's faster reserving a bunch of zeros, because you don't have to fill it up with an other value (as -inf).

Hope helped a little.

Comment: I'm just talking about temporal performance, and not memory performance.